# ReferenceError: string is not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, amazon-web-services, object, for-in-loop

I try to do iteration on object on nodejs using for in, on my local it's working just fine. but when i deploy it to web service, it pass an error.

[but when i tried on my local it work just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6jts.png)

```
const queue = {
    mobilize : 'test',
    mobileTurnOn: 'mobileTurnOn',
    pushAdminNotif: 'pushAdminNotif',
    diffLocationAlert: 'diffLocationAlert'
  };
  for ( string in queue) {
    console.log(string, "key")
    console.log(queue[string], "value")
  };
```

[it said variable is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6V19.png)

> ReferenceError: string is not defined
> 13
> at /app/dist/app.js:59:10
> 12
> at /app/node_modules/amqplib/callback_api.js:15:23
> 11
> at /app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js:154:9
> 10
> at succeed (/app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:283:5)
> 9
> at onOpenOk (/app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:262:5)
> 8
> at /app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:165:32
> 7
> at /app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:159:12
> 6
> at Socket.recv (/app/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connection.js:507:12)
> 5
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
> 4
> at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
> 3
> at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
> 2
> at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:557:12)
> 1
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)

[here is my terminal on my local running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrxOM.png)

Comment: should be `for (let string in queue)`, you have to declare it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for (const string in queue) {
  console.log(string, "key")
  console.log(queue[string], "value")
};
```

Comment: oh my god, can't believe i miss to declare it. so upset with my self haha but it leads me to another questions. why on my local it work just fine ?

Comment: Some js engines, such as V8, will implicitly declare a global variable if you use for in loop without declaring variable(not strict mode). so I think deployed server may be using strict mode. so you need to declare local variable. - @MuzaniPamasarsa